# What is use "[0]" in "input().split()[0]"

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

I this python code I wanted to know what is use of [0] after split()
This is transpose and flatten code

```
array = numpy.array([input().strip().split() for _ in range(int(input().split()[0]))], int)
print (array.transpose())
print (array.flatten()
```

Result :

```
 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
[[1 4 7]
 [2 5 8]
 [3 6 9]]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Comment: My guess: In case the user enters multiple numbers like `3 2 1`, the program will only take the first number as input. That is what `.split()[0]` is for.

Comment: Could you add some more context?

Comment: `[0]` just means to use the first element of a list, tuple, or array.

Comment: I added everything including result

Comment: Can anyone please help me with more information, I'm new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[0]` returns the first element of a list. For example:

Set `a` to a string:

```
>>> a = '4 5 6'
>>> a
'4 5 6'
```

`.split()` returns a list (of strings):

```
>>> a.split()
['4', '5', '6']
```

`[0]` returns the first element of the list.

```
>>> a.split()[0]
'4'
```

If we reduce the input string to a single number:

```
>>> b = '3'
>>> b
'3'
```

`.split()` returns a list of length 1

```
>>> b.split()
['3']
```

Lists can't be directly converted to integers:

```
>>> int(b.split())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

`[0]` returns the first element of the list which can be converted to an int:

```
>>> b.split()[0]
'3'
>>> int(b.split()[0])
3
```

If you know there is only one integer in the string then `.split()[0]` is not required:

```
>>> int(b)
3
```

But this doesn't work if the string contains multiple numbers:

```
>>> int(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 5 6'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really very helpful.